# How to insert json message in modal with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a system in .NET and I need to send a json controller msg to the view and show it in modal.

The user will import a spreadsheet and the spreadsheet will be inserted in the database, at the end of the modal it should appear with the message whether it was sent or not.

Or backend is already working.
 
I need help on the front because when I import, it loads a new page with

["Sent with success"]

(*the messages are in portuguese*) = ["Enviado com sucesso"]

Follows the controller code.

```
public JsonResult UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {

        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            // tdata.ExecuteCommand("truncate table OtherCompanyAssets");  
            if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                string filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                string targetpath = "C:/Users/70561/Documents";
                FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                string pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                var connectionString = "";
                if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", pathToExcelFile);
                }
                else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcelFile);
                }

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Planilha1$]", connectionString);
                var ds = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");

                DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];

                string sheetName = "Planilha1";

                var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
                var dados = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<RETORNO_CM>(sheetName) select a;

                foreach (var a in dados)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (a.CM_CODIGO != null && a.CM_QM_COMPONENTE_RMA != null && a.CM_NS != null && a.CM_DESCRICAO != null &&
                            a.CM_DEFEITO != null && a.J_FALHA != null &&
                            a.CM_TIPO_DEFEITO != null && a.J_PLACA_RETRABALHO != null &&
                            a.J_PLACA_RESTESTADA != null && a.J_STATUS != null && a.CM_NOME_TESTE != null && a.CM_NOME_DEBUG != null)
                        {
                            RETORNO_CM CM = new RETORNO_CM();
                            CM.CM_CODIGO = a.CM_CODIGO;
                            CM.CM_QM_COMPONENTE_RMA = a.CM_QM_COMPONENTE_RMA;
                            CM.CM_NS = a.CM_NS;
                            CM.CM_DESCRICAO = a.CM_DESCRICAO;
                            CM.CM_DATA_REPARO = a.CM_DATA_REPARO;
                            CM.CM_DEFEITO = a.CM_DEFEITO;
                            CM.J_FALHA = a.J_FALHA;
                            CM.CM_TIPO_DEFEITO = a.CM_TIPO_DEFEITO;
                            CM.CM_COMPONENTE = a.CM_COMPONENTE;
                            CM.J_PLACA_RETRABALHO = a.J_PLACA_RETRABALHO;
                            CM.J_PLACA_RESTESTADA = a.J_PLACA_RESTESTADA;
                            CM.J_STATUS = a.J_STATUS;
                            CM.CM_NOME_TESTE = a.CM_NOME_TESTE;
                            CM.CM_NOME_DEBUG = a.CM_NOME_DEBUG;
                            db.RETORNO_CM.Add(CM);

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.Add("<ul>");

                            data.Add("</ul>");
                            data.ToArray();
                            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                    }

                    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                    {
                        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {

                            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //deleting excel file from folder  
                if ((System.IO.File.Exists(pathToExcelFile)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
                }
                data.Add("Enviado com sucesso");
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("Apenas arquivos excel sao suportados");
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("Selecione um arquivo");
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

my view code

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-body">
    <hr />
    <article class="table-responsive" style="overflow:hidden">
        <p class="lead">Teste de importação.</p>
        <hr />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "RetornoCM", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return myFunction()" }))
        {
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="control-label col-md-2">Escolha o Arquivo:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>
                            <b>Message:</b><br>
                            <input class="message-edit-text" type="text" size="20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling this method?, using ajax?

Comment: Can you post the code that calls this action please. I'm thinking there is an issue with the call, along the same lines as @Hackerman

Comment: updated the question with view code sry

Comment: You should not return JSON, as you are performing a *full page postback*. You should either return a view or use Ajax request at the beginning.

Comment: Win, after lunch I'll try ur example...thx =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not return JSON, as you are performing a full page postback. Instead, you should return a ***View***.

If you do not want to perform a full page postback, you want to use ***Ajax*** since the beginning of the request.

*For example,*

### View

Please make sure button is `type="button"` to avoid full page postback.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "RetornoCM", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Escolha o Arquivo:</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Enviar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {

            // Checking whether FormData is available in browser
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

                var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;

                // Create FormData object
                var fileData = new FormData();

                // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UploadExcel", "RetornoCM")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                    processData: false, // Not to process data
                    data: fileData,
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

### Action Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadExcel()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                // Do somethig with file
            }
            return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("No files selected.");
    }
}
```

*Source: [File Upload Through JQuery AJAX In ASP.NET MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/upload-files-through-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)*